# Sample for wpf detail master view

Tags: c#, wpf, master-detail

I'm new to WPF. i need to  implement a list box( collection of data) , picture box and a some description to be display related to each row of listBox.Can any one suggest a good example of WPF detail master related to this situation .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a nice MSDN Article [How to: Use the Master-Detail Pattern with Hierarchical Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742531.aspx)

I would also recommend reading [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

dont forget to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"`